# Последовательность пайпов ( .pipe() )

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm, frontend

Начал осваивать сборщики проектов, а именно из Gulp.

Я уловил, что .pipe() предназначен для передачи потока данных по цепочке, то есть он задаёт последовательность выполнения плагинов в пределах одной задачи.

Но объясните мне, пожалуйста, по каким принципам строится сама упорядоченность .pipe()?

```
gulp.task('useref', function(){
  var assets = useref.assets();

  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
 .pipe(assets)
 .pipe(uglify()) 
 .pipe(assets.restore())
 .pipe(useref())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

Почему, допустим, .pipe(assets) располагается выше, чем .pipe(useref()), или по какой причине .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')) располагается последним в списке? В каких документациях об этом написано? После прочтения каких материалов или прохождения какой практики можно научиться понимать, чувствовать в каком порядке укладывать .pipe()?

Answer (score 0):

**gulp.src('app/*.html')*** - те данные что берём, поэтому в начале (в данном случае все *html* файлы в каталоге *app*). 
**.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))** - пишет переданные данные в файл, поэтому в конце.

```
.pipe(assets)
.pipe(uglify()) 
.pipe(assets.restore())
.pipe(useref())
```

Цепочка плагинов в порядке который нужен вам. Плагин получает данные, изменяет их, и передает дальше.

Почитать можно в [документации(eng)](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs).И не плохой, дающий общее представление, [вводный мануал](https://webdesign-master.ru/blog/tools/2016-03-09-gulp-beginners.html)